# How to integrate R script with SQL server

Tags: sql, r

I have a R script that does some predictive analysis. Now, I want to call this script from SQL server that will fetch the data from server and after processing the data it will again write in SQL server. Does anyone knows how to do this??

Comment: We are supposed to help you not before you try to help your self. Show us what is your script and what you have done sofar towards solving your problem

Comment: Which version of SQL server you are using?  In the current versin, R is integrated with SQL server management studio

Comment: I am using the latest version of SQL but I am unable to call SQL data into R. Below is my code:
data <- read_excel('sales_data_for_predictive.xlsx',sheet=2)
#Selecting model and bla bla. Not mention here since it is too big.
model <- train(lrn, trainTask)
predicted <- predict(model,testTask)
sub <- data.frame(w,Predicted=abs(predicted$data$response))
write_csv(sub,"xgbost.csv")